# Regex: how to replace all nested double quotes inside an xml attribute

Tags: regex, xml

I have this xml which could have nested double quotes (not escaped) inside attributes:

```
<test>
    <tag1 att1="This has "nested double quotes"">
        <tag2 att2="This also has a nested " double quotes"></tag2>
    </tag1>
</test>
```

I need to find a regex which will select all the nested double quotes, in this case

- `"`nested double quotes`"`
- nested `"` double

and replace them with the `&quot;` character. The final xml should be like the following:

```
<test>
    <tag1 att1="This has &quot;nested double quotes&quot;">
        <tag2 att2="This also has a nested &quot; double quotes"></tag2>
    </tag1>
</test>
```

Is it possible to achieve this using regex?

Comment: It is _possible_ to achieve this using regex?  Maybe, but now would be a good time to learn how to use an XML parser!  It will give me massively more reliable results than regex would.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Unfortunately I have no control over the xml source so I have to fix the problem my self. I agree that it should be properly escaped from the beginning, but can't do anything about that